# csv.dictreader does not give desired output

Tags: python

Merry Christmas!

I have the following data:

```
a = ("   101,   151,     0,'T1',2,2,1, 1.71470E-1,-1.02880E-1,2,'NUCA GSU    ',1,   1,0.3200,   2,0.3900,   3,0.1400,   4,0.1500",
 "1.10000E-3, 9.10000E-2,  1200.00",
"21.6000,  21.600,   0.000,  1200.00,  1100.00,  1000.00, 1,    101,22.68000,20.52000, 1.05000, 0.95000,  25, 0, 0.00021, 0.00051",
"500.000, 500.000")

b = (('I','J','K','CKT','CW','CZ','CM','MAG1','MAG2','NMETR','NAME',
             'STAT','O1','F1','O2','F2','O3','F3','O4','F4'),
            ('R1-2','X1-2','SBASE1-2'),
            ('WINDV1','NOMV1','ANG1','RATA1','RATB1','RATC1','COD1','CONT1',
             'RMA1','RMI1','VMA1','VMI1','NTP1','TAB1','CR1','CX1'),
            ('WINDV2','NOMV2'))
```

I would like to form a dict as follows:

```
{'I': 101, 'J': 151, ...... 'F4': 0.1500}
{'R1-2': 1.10000E-3, ...... 'SBASE1-2': 1200.0}
{'WINDV1': 21.60, ...... 'ÇX1': 0.00051}
{'WINDV2': 500.0, 'NOMV2': 500.0}
```

I want to use csv.DicReader so I tried the following code:

```
for j in range(4):
    c=list(csv.DictReader(a[j], fieldnames=b[j]))
    print c
```

I am not getting the desired output. What am I doing wrong?

I can already do it like this:

```
for j in range(4):
    c=dict(zip( b[j], (a[j].split(','))))
    print c
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's simpler doing it without csv.DictReader, you aren't reading a CSV.

```
newListOfDict=[]
for keyLine, valueLine in zip(b, a): #one and one line from a and b
    #the string line in b splitted and stripped
    splittedValues = map(lambda v: v.strip(), valueLine.split(","))
    #create the new dict with the result of zip : ((b1, a1),(b2, a2)...)
    newDict = dict(zip(keyLine, splittedValues))
    newListOfDict.append(newDict)
print newListOfDict
```